# Having own library units in the same build config as the project

Tags: delphi, build, delphi-11-alexandria, delphi-units

How can I setup Delphi library folders so I can have both Debug and Release versions of my units library when I work on a project ? Until now I compiled my library in Release mode once is finished. But I encountered situations when I work on a project and I need to follow the debugging steps even in the compiled units. But if they are compiled as Release, it won't let me. And if I compile them as Debug, it puts the debuging code in the Release version of the project, which is not normal. I would like that when I switch between Debug and Release in my project, the units also switch. Can it be done ? If I put both Debug and Releas folders in Delphi library path, it will know when to choose te right one ?

Comment: Why do you need to debug the release version? Also, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow - you would be better off asking in [Delphi Praxis](https://en.delphipraxis.net).

Comment: The question is unclear. Are the libraries part of the project or are they separate? Please consider giving a more detailed example.

Comment: @UweRaabe It is about a general library (made by me). It is not part of the project.

Comment: You probably want the "Debug DCU Path" in Options -> Language -> Delphi -> Library, The convention is to put the pre-compiled debug DCUs in a subfolder named "debug"

Comment: So, in "Debug DCU Path" I put units compiled with Debug mode and in "Library Path" the Release version ?

Comment: Delphi IDE can use Debug Win32 version of DCU, DCL and BPL, it's not problem. To make a building of your application corectly you can do next steps: set `Output directory` of your library something like `$(MyLibraryPath)\Bin\$(Platform)\$(Config)`, than add into `Search path` of your application same value. After that Delphi compiler will take correct version of library in all cases. It will replace `$(Platform)` into `Win32` or `Win64` and `$(Config)` into `Release` or `Debug` depense of current buiding params.  `$(MyLibraryPath)`can be some absolute path or add such enviroment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to understand how it works: the key is `$(Platform)` and `$(Config)`.

I made a test unit with a function that tells me what configuration I'm using:

```
unit Test;

interface

function GetConfig: String;

implementation

function GetConfig: String;
begin
 {$IFDEF RELEASE} Result:= 'Release'; {$ENDIF}
 {$IFDEF DEBUG} Result:= 'Debug'; {$ENDIF}
end;

end.
```

I compiled it in Debug and Release mode and saved `.dcu` files in D:\Delphi\MyLIB\Win32 \Release and \Debug. And the `.pas` in the D:\Delphi\MySRC. Then I go to Tools > Options > Language > Delphi > Library and I added `D:\Delphi\MyLIB\$(Platform)\$(Config)` to Library Path section and 'D:\Delphy\MySRC' to Browsing Path.

Now, if I make a new project and use that unit, the correct version is selected according to Buid Configuration. And if I switch to Debug and do a `Trace Into (F7)` over that function, I can debug inside it.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Test;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Caption:= GetConfig;
end;

end.
```

Thanks to `Oleksandr Morozevych` comment !